# Salesforce: Best approach to create opportunities via API without Salesforce Account ID

Tags: api, integration, opportunity, account

We have the following situation: We are planning to integrate our 3rd party Webshop with Salesforce. We are going to use a middleware. Each order from the webshop should create an opportunity in Salesforce. Customers can order on the webshop as guests and do not have to register/login. In these cases we do not get an account ID via API.

At the moment we consider to have one dummy account to which we assign all new opportunities.
A user would need to monitor these opportunities, check the account information (name + address) in
a description field of the opportunity. The same user would need to manually check, if there is already an account in Salesforce for that customer.

If yes: The user assigns the opportunity to that account and changes the opportunity owner to the account owner.

If no: The user creates the account in Salesforce and then assigns it to the opportunity.

Is there any better way to do this? We would prefer a more automated way.
If not, can we bypass the mandatory account field on the opportunity via API?

I do not like the idea of having a dummy account in the system, as this feels quite oldschool and dirty ;)

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option

- The [schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm) allows Opportunities to be inserted without an `AccountId` - i.e. via REST API from the middleware
- Users would monitor Opportunities without AccountIds via a ListView or Report.
- Then, using Edit on the Opportunity, assign the Account (as Account is required on the standard edit page)

The above works fine as long as these Opportunities don't need editing via their detail page prior to account assignment